# Why would a function end with "return 0" instead of "return" in python?

Tags: python, function, return

Could you please explain the difference between "return 0" and "return"?
For example:

```
do_1():
    for i in xrange(5):
        do_sth()
    return 0

do_2():
    for i in xrange(5):
        do_sth()
    return
```

What is the difference between two functions above?

Comment: `return` returns `None`

Comment: Worth noting that if you omitted the return at the end of the "do_2" function the return value would still be None. You can close a function without the return just by dedenting out of the block and it will return None.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Depends on usage:

```
>>> def ret_Nothing():
...     return
... 
>>> def ret_None():
...     return None
... 
>>> def ret_0():
...     return 0
... 
>>> ret_Nothing() == None
True
>>> ret_Nothing() is None  # correct way to compare values with None
True
>>> ret_None() is None
True
>>> ret_0() is None
False
>>> ret_0() == 0
True
>>> # and...
>>> repr(ret_Nothing())
'None'
```

And as [mentioned by Tichodroma](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12348735/1431750), `0` is not equal to `None`. However, in **boolean context**, they are both `False`:

```
>>> if ret_0():
...     print 'this will not be printed'
... else:
...     print '0 is boolean False'
... 
0 is boolean False
>>> if ret_None():
...     print 'this will not be printed'
... else:
...     print 'None is also boolean False'
... 
None is also boolean False
```

More on Boolean context in Python: [Truth Value Testing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing)

Answer (score 5):

In Python, **every** function returns a return value, either implicitly or explicitly.

```
>>> def foo():
...     x = 42
... 
>>> def bar():
...     return
... 
>>> def qux():
...     return None
... 
>>> def zero():
...     return 0
... 
>>> print foo()
None
>>> print bar()
None
>>> print qux()
None
>>> print zero()
0
```

As you can see, `foo`, `bar` and `qux` return exactly the same, the built in constant [**`None`**](http://docs.python.org/library/constants.html#None).

- `foo` returns `None` because a `return` statement is missing and `None` is the default return value if a function doesn't explicitly return a value.
- `bar` returns `None` because it uses a `return` statement without an argument, which also defaults to `None`.
- `qux` returns `None` because it explicitly does so.

`zero` however is entirely different and returns the [integer **`0`**](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-long-complex).

If [evaluated as booleans](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing), `0` and `None` both evaluate to `False`, but besides that, they are very different (different types in fact, `NoneType` and `int`).

Answer (score 4):

```
def do_1():
    return 0

def do_2():
    return

# This is the difference
do_1 == 0 # => True
do_2 == 0 # => False
```

Comment: That is _one_ difference, but it doesn't explain at all what's going on.

Answer (score 4):

In python, a function would return `None` either explicitly or implicitly.

e.g.

```
# Explicit
def get_user(id):
    user = None
    try:
        user = get_user_from_some_rdbms_byId(id)
    except:
        # Our RDBMS raised an exception because the ID was not found.
        pass
    return user  # If it is None, the caller knows the id was not found.

# Implicit
def add_user_to_list(user):
    user_list.append(user)   # We don't return something, so implicitly we return None
```

A python function would return `0` either because of some computation:

```
def add_2_numbers(a,b):
    return a + b      # 1 -1 would return 0
```

Or because of a `magic` flag kind of thing, which is frowned upon.

But in python we don't use `0` to denote success because this:

```
if get_user(id):
```

would not evaluate to `True` if we returned `0` therefore this `if` branch would not run.

```
In [2]: bool(0)
Out[2]: False
```

Answer (score 3):

it has nothing to do specifically with python.

whenever you perform a function you can optionally return a value.

the `return` keyword is what informs the function if it should return a value or not.

if no value is given to the `return` or no variable is assigned to be returned, then the return value is `None`

if you assign a value, in this case, `0` to be returned, then the value `0` will be returned by the function and the function will end when the `return` keyword and value is reached.

some more information on `0`:
the reason a `0` would be used is because it is commonplace that functions which return `0` were "successful" and non-zero return values are either simply the value to be returned, or sometimes error codes if the function did not perform correctly.

Comment: In python you wouldn't return `0` for denoting success.

Comment: All this is _very_ specific to Python.

Comment: And functions also return something (`None`) if a `return` statement is omitted.